# Create mulitple geofencing region and track them?

Tags: ios, geofencing

in My Application presently i am tracking 1 CLCircularRegion so my question is that how can i track multiple region at same time .

what I am doing now is :
   I am calculation in didUpdateLocation for that one region and it is working fine for it and now my concern is that if i do that calculation for multiple region tahn it will slow down my app so is there a better way to track multiple geofenceing Area :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
    // NSLog(@"crnLoc is %@",crnLoc);



    NSLog(@"my Location Info is %@",locations);

        NSSet * monitoredRegions = locationManager.monitoredRegions;
        if(monitoredRegions)
        {



            [monitoredRegions enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CLRegion *region,BOOL *stop)
             {
                 NSString *identifer = region.identifier;
                 CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoords =region.center;
                 CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCoords= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(crnLoc.coordinate.latitude,crnLoc.coordinate.longitude);
                 CLLocationDistance radius = 20.0;

                 NSNumber * currentLocationDistance =[self calculateDistanceInMetersBetweenCoord:currentCoords coord:centerCoords];
                 if([currentLocationDistance floatValue] < radius)
                 {
                     //NSLog(@"Invoking didEnterRegion Manually for region: %@",identifer);

                     //stop Monitoring Region temporarily
                    // [locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];

                     [self locationManager:locationManager didEnterRegion:region];
                     //start Monitoing Region again.
                    // [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
                 }else{
                     [self locationManager:locationManager didExitRegion:region];
                 }
             }];

        //Stop Location Updation, we dont need it now.
        //[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

   // }

}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using region tracking that is built in to Core Location?

Comment: Paul - In this code it has already used CoreLocation Framework and calling didEnterRegion and didExitRegion after calculation in didUpdateLocation.

Comment: The code is manually invoking `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` - These delegate methods will be called automatically by Core Location if the in-built region monitoring is used.

Comment: thanks paul -- please share your code so that it will help someone.

Comment: It is covered in the Apple programming guide - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW2